# subfig package makes my table's caption vertical

Tags: tables, captions, subfloats

I am transforming a paper from `\documentclass[Journal]{IEEEtran}` to `\documentclass{ifacconf}`. There is no problem with IEEE version although in this new version if I use `\usepackage{subfig}` the caption becomes vertical and appears one-word-in-a-line. 
When I use `\usepackage{subfig}` the result is:
[image]

and when I don't, the result is:
[image]

I have to use subfig because I have subfloat in my writing which cannot compile without it. 
I have tried `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`.

ADDED!
Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
%=============table
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}    % maybe too dark?
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{4, 5, 31}
\definecolor{line1}{RGB}{224, 224, 209}
\definecolor{line2}{RGB}{253, 198, 199}
\definecolor{grayover}{RGB}{163, 163, 194}
\definecolor{line3}{RGB}{117, 117, 163}
\definecolor{line4}{RGB}{224, 224, 209}
\definecolor{line5}{RGB}{140, 179, 217}
\definecolor{ruler}{RGB}{182, 177, 175}

%\arrayrulecolor{mycolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}     % 18pt seems extravagant
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5} % 2.5 seems excessive
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\raggedright}p{5cm}}

%=============table
%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
    \section{Sec 1}
    \clearpage
    \begin{table*}[]
        \centering
        \caption{Recent Research Contributions in Parallel and Distributed Simulation - Summary}
        \label{table:tab1}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{rcccccl}

            \end{tabular}}%
        \end{table*}%
    \clearpage

\section{Figures }
    \begin{figure*}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \subfloat[caption for this]{\label{fig:A}
            \resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
                %A tik picture that works fine goes here
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }%
        %\hfill 
        \subfloat[caption for this]{\label{fig:B}
            \resizebox{5cm}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
                %another tikz picture here
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }%
        \hfill 

        \subfloat[Select the pair of processes with maximum edge cost, insert in queue (B,C)]{\label{fig:C}
            \resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
                %and another here
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }%
        \hfill
        \newline
        \hfill
        \caption{Execution Model}\label{fig:G}
        \end{figure*}
    \end{document}
```

The document template can be downloaded from [this link](https://www.ifac-control.org/events/author-guide/copy_of_ifacconf_latex.zip/at_download/file)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the work is related to my thesis so I refrain from posting it. But \subfloat  is working fine in the first paper

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized this wasn't about a `\subfloat`. a) You shouldn't post the whole thing in the first place, only the what is needed to reproduce the problem. For example `\documentclass{ifacconf} \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} \usepackage{natbib} \begin{document} \begin{table} \caption{foo bar baz} \begin{tabular}{c} a \end{tabular} \end{table} \end{document}` b) Replace the content with dummy text if you don't want to show the content. c) A link to where `ifacconf.cls` can be downloaded should be included in the question.

Comment: ok let me edit it with complete details

Comment: @TorbjørnT. please take a look at the updates

Comment: Do you have the same issue with a common `article` class ?

Comment: You should test your example before posting, that one gives a `Package graphics Error: Division by 0.` because the `tabular` in your `\resizebox` is empty. But the `\resizebox` and `tabular` isn't really needed in the first place, you can just remove it.

Comment: @BambOo no it just creates the problem in this one